# Discussion about a holding case - Ask people to test a project in their environment

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I'm here to talk about this case: [The Sails.js controller action is called twice during every HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612432/sails-js-framework-controller-action-called-twice-in-each-http-request)

I asked for help about something that after several hours of debug I couldn't understand, at the end I assumed that the error was from the `sails` framework. So I created a github repo with an example and the result of my test and a screen. The problem was quite simple: Each HTTP request called twice my controller's method. That's all and I had no clue why.

In first place, people decided to downvote my question, without any explanation, I asked why, but no answer, that's frustrating. If I'm doing wrong I appreciate to know why, to correct myself. After 4 down votes without any explanation, I got a bit angry. I'm someone polite and I expect to get the same from other people. Downvoting without explanation when a question is fulfilled with screen, explanation and test is impolite. I spent time to do it and I don't like waste my time.

Then someone told me that I must explain everything in the question's body. But in this precise case I couldn't! I didn't have a clue about the issue, only other people with more knowledge than me could find a solution or ask the good questions.

Then `sails` users saw my case on the sails google group and used my test to ask the good questions and tell me that it worked fine in their environment, so the problem was coming from mine. After a few messages we found out that was because of a browser plugin that send double request.

I would like my question reopened and add a proper answer to it since we found the solution to the issue. The downvote wasn't appropriate there, the question only needed someone competent/ready to clone the repo and test on his environment and help me.

I agree that in most case we need to have as much information as possible in the question's body. But I don't see how I could have done that in this situation. Human tests were required.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update**:

I've edited your question to show you what you're missing and how you could have made it better. Because you inserted the image into a Google Doc, I couldn't add it as a screenshot, but if you'd be so kind as to include the screenshot as an image into your post, that would be helpful. If you can't do that due to reputation, then at least link to the actual image itself so someone with the right amount of reputation can do that.

You should not expect this level of help from anyone at Stack Overflow.  What I've shown by editing your question is an example of how you need to approach future questions.  If you approach future questions like you approached this one, your questions will be downvoted and closed, and you'll likely be system-banned.

**Original Post**:

One of the tenets of Stack Overflow is that a question should have utility for a future visitor, and that's part of the impetus for this close reason:

> "This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or ***[include a minimal example in the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)***."  (emphasis added)

Have you included a minimal example in the question itself?  Not really, no.  You have included a few links, but nothing that helps us reproduce your issue.

The problem with those external links is that if any of them 404, your question becomes useless to future visitors.

That's a bad user experience for everyone who might happen upon your question (extra frustrating for people who have the same problem you do).

If you can't reproduce your problem in a minimal example, that means that you really don't know enough about the actual problem to bring it to us to help you.  That's one of the reasons we have that guideline in place:  through the course of reproducing this issue in a minimal environment, you may even solve it (And that's a good thing).  Even if you don't solve it, you'll take out all the extraneous factors that don't matter, and that helps us solve your problem for you.

Your question was put on-hold to give you the opportunity to help us solve your problem.  We can't help you solve your problem if you don't give us what we need.

The Screenshot should be in your question; the smallest amount of code needed to reproduce your question should be in the question, and instead of links, you should describe your problem in the same way you'd search for it.

We require this minimal level of effort on your part.  Those are the table stakes for coming to Stack Overflow.

To give you a better idea of what you're missing from your question:

The example you give *in the external link* is not an out of the box "hello world" example.  You have a controller called `userController` that you should share, because that's the code you wrote. If you also created your own route, you should share that as well.

You're also missing that you're seeing this *while debugging in WebStorm*, and not just running it 'stock'.

When I did install your application and run it 'stock', I saw **one** "test" output to the console, and one output to the browser, which exactly matches the code you've written. *I did not see the word "test" twice.*

Unless you can provide more information, we can't help you -- because even when I jumped through your hoops, I can't reproduce your issue.